# Spring data xml configuration schema validation error

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring, spring-data

I have a project using Spring (context, transaction, apect) 4.1.6.RELEASE and spring-data-jpa 1.8.0.RELEASE and encountering strange errors, assumingly caused by xsd validation. However, I cannot figrue out the cause. Strangely, the projects runs fine, all my beans are correctly recognized.

I'm using Eclipse luna and Spring Tools Suite plugin

I removed everything from my applicationContext.xml except the "jpa:" line which causes problems. The xml has been created with the STS plugin.

I tried to remove version numbers from the xsds, without success.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem some time ago, all errors were caused by jpa thing
i moved the jpa configuration to a new configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    default-destroy-method="destroy"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.some.validator" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.some.security.rest" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.some.repository.path"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</beans>
```

some maven imports:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

and spring framework version

```
    <org.springframework-version>4.1.7.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
```

Try to clean project and update it with maven

Comment: The only answer that worked for my, although I find the solution not really satisfying....

Comment: there are some compability problems with different jpa versions

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem than you and it came from the versions of the xsd files. In particular, the issue went away when I remove the spring Context XSD version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd      
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.app.repositories" />
</beans>
```

That XML file does not generate any validation error for me.

Cheers,

Emmanuel

Comment: still the same problem with your XML: "Description Resource Path Location Type Referenced file contains errors (project-aware://butler-sync/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.1.xsd), location Line 1"

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve these XML validation problems, you can try to remove the version notations completely, as shown below, and let Spring load generic schema locations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schem...ring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schem...ng-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schem...spring-jpa.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">
```

Inclusion of generic or version-ed `XSD` schema locations produce no different results for the application behavior. Also, try to reorganize your `pom.xml` and make sure that transient dependencies were resolved with the correct version.

Strange part of this resolution is that it worked for me in few applications but failed to work in others where I was getting the same error. For me, sometimes changing version-ed `XSDs` to generic and then again changing them back to version-ed have worked out. Eclipse Luna-*tic* behavior!

*PS: No offense intended for Eclipse lovers.*